# How to display json data in UIWebview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uiwebview

I am trying to display json data in UIWebview.This is my json data

```
["{\"id\":\"6\",\"title\":null,\"description\":null,\"year\":\"2012\",\"date\":null}","{\"id\":\"4\",\"title\":\"Predictions proved correct in the year 2013\",\"description\":\"*<\\\/font> Financial system in America for this year is not indicated progress this year too. More problems will creep up.
\\r\\n*<\\\/font> Aggressive stage of Telangaana agitation- formation of seperate Telangaana state- bifurcation of state - sure indications are \\r\\n\\r\\npredicted.
\\r\\n*<\\\/font> Bad days for congress party was predicted long back. The same situations will continue.
\\r\\n*<\\\/font> The Gujarath CM - Sri Narendra Modi - Bright future is indicated. ( Care should be taken on health aspects).
\\r\\n*<\\\/font> Still danger is indicated for Indoneshia and Sumitra Islands\",\"year\":\"2013\",\"date\":null}"

{\"id\":\"3\",\"title\":\"2013-2014 Sri Vijayanama samvasthara Predictions\",\"description\":\"
జోతిస్యం అక్షర సత్యం
\\r\\nతెలంగాణా ఏర్పాటును గ్రహగతులు అనుసరించి మాత్రమే ఈ ఫలితము చెప్పడం జరిగింది . చరిత్రతమకమెన తెలంగాణా విషయంలో ములుగు సిద్ధాంతి వార్త పంచాంగంలో వ్రాసిన విధంగా అక్షరాల జరిగింది.
ప్రేత్యక తెలంగాణా విసయంలో అనేక రకాల మలుపులు తిరిగి ఎక్కడఎన ఆటంకం వస్తుందేమోనని బావించిన సందర్బాలు కూడా ఉన్నాయ్.
2011- 2012 శ్రీ ఖరనామ సవత్సరం వార్త పంచాంగంలో (58 వ పేజి , 18 లైనులో ) 2013-2014 శ్రీ విజయనామ సవత్సరం వార్త పంచాంగంలో తెలంగానా ఏర్పడుతుందని (40 వ పేజి 5 వ లైనులో )సిద్ధాంతి గారు వ్రాయడం జరిగింది
\\r\\n\\r\\nగమనిక : ఎంతోమంది జ్యోతిష్య, శాస్త్రవేత్తలు, సిద్దంతులు తలక్రిందులుగా తపస్సు చేసిన తెలంగాణా రాదనే చెప్పారు. ఒక్క ములుగు సిద్ధాంతి మాత్రమే మొదటి నుంచి చెబుతూనే వచ్చారు .\",\"year\":\"2014\",\"date\":null}"]
```

Now i need to display like this:

- Financial system in America for this year is not indicated progress this year too. More problems will creep up.

*Aggressive stage of Telangaana agitation- formation of seperate Telangaana state- bifurcation of state - sure indications are predicted.

- Bad days for congress party was predicted long back. The same situations will continue.
- The Gujarath CM - Sri Narendra Modi - Bright future is indicated. ( Care should be taken on health aspects).
- Still danger is indicated for Indoneshia and Sumitra Islands.
- జోతిస్యం అక్షర సత్యం
  తెలంగాణా ఏర్పాటును గ్రహగతులు అనుసరించి మాత్రమే ఈ ఫలితము చెప్పడం జరిగింది . చరిత్రతమకమెన తెలంగాణా విషయంలో ములుగు సిద్ధాంతి వార్త పంచాంగంలో వ్రాసిన విధంగా అక్షరాల జరిగింది.
  ప్రేత్యక తెలంగాణా విసయంలో అనేక రకాల మలుపులు తిరిగి ఎక్కడఎన ఆటంకం వస్తుందేమోనని బావించిన సందర్బాలు కూడా ఉన్నాయ్.
  2011- 2012 శ్రీ ఖరనామ సవత్సరం వార్త పంచాంగంలో (58 వ పేజి , 18 లైనులో ) 2013-2014 శ్రీ విజయనామ సవత్సరం వార్త పంచాంగంలో తెలంగానా ఏర్పడుతుందని (40 వ పేజి 5 వ లైనులో )  సిద్ధాంతి గారు వ్రాయడం జరిగింది

గమనిక : ఎంతోమంది జ్యోతిష్య, శాస్త్రవేత్తలు, సిద్దంతులు తలక్రిందులుగా తపస్సు చేసిన తెలంగాణా రాదనే చెప్పారు. ఒక్క సిద్ధాంతి మాత్రమే మొదటి నుంచి చెబుతూనే వచ్చారు

I am writing like this:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

if(connection==urlConnection)

{

strResponse=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@",strResponse);

NSError *error;

jsonDict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@",jsonDict);

NSLog(@"object class == %@",[jsonDict class]);

stringArray=[jsonDict valueForKey:@"description"];

NSLog(@"%@",stringArray);

webView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];

[webView loadHTMLString:strResponse baseURL:nil];

[self.view addSubview:webView];

}

}

-(void)loadData

{

NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults valueForKey:@"id"];

[defaults valueForKey:@"title"];

[defaults valueForKey:@"description"];

[defaults synchronize];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

urlConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

}
```

Comment: When you already do need to parse the data, why not use UITableView instead? You can convert the JSON stream into NSDictionary or NSArray using NSJSONSerialization

Comment: i need to display only in uiview or uiwebview.in telugu font also i want to display it.

Comment: First, go through parsing the JSON data using NSJSONSerialization. Showing it in a UIView will be relatively simple.

Comment: plz come to stack over flow chat. i want to chat with u.i have lot of doubts.PLZ come to Talk-4-ios blog.

Comment: help me any body........

Comment: You're going to have to parse the JSON and then run some logic that knows how to transcribe the JSON into the sort of HTML format you want.  You may get lucky and find a JSON "prettyprinter" javascript app that comes close.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><p>here you json data</p></html>"];
    [myWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: bro.i can't understand about this line of code...    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><p>here you json data</p></html>", 300, 300];

Comment: Sorry I've a simple error, I did edit my answer. In this line you are creating a string with html format, then you pass this string to the uiwebview. Do you know html?

Comment: i have know idea bro.plz tell me briefly.i need to find a solution to my issue.Please help me bro

Comment: I'm pretty sure all that's going to do is show the JSON as a blob of unintelligible characters.